# Linq Group By Count single column

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have my linq as below:

```
from ucd in UserCategoryDetails
join uc in UserCategories on ucd.UserCategoryDetailsID equals
        uc.UserCategoryDetailsID into ucj from uc in ucj.DefaultIfEmpty()
join uct in UserCategoryTypes on ucd.UserCategoryTypeID equals
        uct.UserCategoryTypeID
join cc in UserCategoryColours on ucd.UserCategoryColourID equals 
         cc.UserCategoryColourID
where 
        ucd.UserCategoryTypeID == 2 && 
        ucd.UserID == 1
group ucd by new { 
        ucd.UserCategoryDetailsID, 
        ucd.CategoryName, 
        cc.UserCategoryColourID, 
        cc.ImageSrcLarge, 
        cc.ImageSrcSmall 
    } into g
select new  {
        UserCategoryDetailsID = g.Key.UserCategoryDetailsID,
        CategoryName = g.Key.CategoryName,
        CategoryColourID = g.Key.UserCategoryColourID,
        ImageSrcLarge = g.Key.ImageSrcLarge,
        ImageSrcSmall = g.Key.ImageSrcSmall,
        CategoryCount = g.Count()
}
```

The trouble is the sql the `Count()` generates is `COUNT(*)`, which is messing up the results as it returns 1 when the are no rows in UserCategories.

Can someone show me how to generate the LINQ equivalent of `COUNT(uc.ProjectID)` please? Basically the following SQL statement but in linq:

```
SELECT 
    [t0].[UserCategoryDetailsID], [t0].[CategoryName], 
    [t3].[UserCategoryColourID], [t3].[ImageSrcLarge], 
    [t3].[ImageSrcSmall], COUNT([t1].ProjectID) AS [CategoryCount]
FROM 
    [UserCategoryDetails] AS [t0]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [UserCategory] AS [t1] ON 
            [t0].[UserCategoryDetailsID]) = [t1].[UserCategoryDetailsID]
        INNER JOIN [UserCategoryType] AS [t2] ON 
            [t0].[UserCategoryTypeID] = [t2].[UserCategoryTypeID]
        INNER JOIN [UserCategoryColour] AS [t3] ON 
            [t0].[UserCategoryColourID] = [t3].[UserCategoryColourID]
WHERE 
    ([t0].[UserCategoryTypeID] = 2) AND ([t0].[UserID] = 1)
GROUP BY 
    [t0].[UserCategoryDetailsID], [t0].[CategoryName], 
    [t3].[UserCategoryColourID], [t3].[ImageSrcLarge], 
    [t3].[ImageSrcSmall]
```

Comment: Is this LINQ-to-SQL, or LINQ-to-Entities? Do these objects have navigation properties between each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It would appear that because it was doing `COUNT(*)`, it would return `null` when the project id was null, as mentioned by Jay.  This would then be seen as 1 in the count, screwing up the results.

Changing the count part of the select to below works nicely:

```
CategoryCount = g.Where(grp => grp != null).Count()
```

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, of course, but it looks to me like your LINQ query's `COUNT(*)` is operating on the grouping, rather than on `UserCategory`.

What happens if you replace `g.Count()` with `uc.Count()`?

`COUNT(*)` won't return 1 if the table has no rows. `COUNT(ProjectId)` will be lower than `COUNT(*)` only if there are 1 or more rows in the table and the `ProjectId` column is `NULL` in one or more of those rows.

Comment: If i replace `g.Count()` with `uc.Count()` i get the error 'The name 'uc' does not exist in the current context'.  Also my apologies if i wasn't clear, you are right in saying that ProjectId is NULL.